# how to use and customize MessageConversion(Spring websocket client)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, websocket, stomp

I wrote a web socket server and a client with spring. The codes is following. The codes sending message to server work, but the sesssion.subscribe method cannot receive message from the server. I search for many documents and check my codes. I don't why it cannot work.

Here is my client codes:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread thread = new Thread(new WebsocketThread());
        thread.start();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}

class MyStompSessionHandler extends StompSessionHandlerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void afterConnected(StompSession session, StompHeaders connectedHeaders) {
        session.send("/app/messages", "{'payload3':2222}".getBytes());
        session.subscribe("/user/queue/position-updates", new StompFrameHandler() {

            @Override
            public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
                return String.class;
            }

            @Override
            public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
                System.out.println("test:" + payload);
            }

        });
    }
}

class WebsocketThread implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        List<Transport> transports = new ArrayList<>(1);
        transports.add(new WebSocketTransport( new StandardWebSocketClient()) );
        WebSocketClient webSocketClient = new SockJsClient(transports);
        WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(webSocketClient);

        String url = "ws://127.0.0.1:8860/orders";
        StompSessionHandler sessionHandler = new MyStompSessionHandler();
        ListenableFuture<StompSession> future = stompClient.connect(url, sessionHandler);
    }
}
```

Here is my server codes:

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;

    @MessageMapping("/messages")
    public void sendUserMsg(String messages) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("webSocket:" + messages);
        simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/queue/position-updates", "This is return message");
    }
}
```

It is Exception:

org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: No suitable converter, payloadType=class java.lang.String, handlerType=class com.example.hello.MyStompSessionHandler
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.DefaultStompSession.invokeHandler(DefaultStompSession.java:419)
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.DefaultStompSession.handleMessage(DefaultStompSession.java:373)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient$WebSocketTcpConnectionHandlerAdapter.handleMessage(WebSocketStompClient.java:342)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.AbstractClientSockJsSession.handleMessageFrame(AbstractClientSockJsSession.java:267)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.AbstractClientSockJsSession.handleFrame(AbstractClientSockJsSession.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.WebSocketTransport$ClientSockJsWebSocketHandler.handleTextMessage(WebSocketTransport.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.AbstractWebSocketHandler.handleMessage(AbstractWebSocketHandler.java:43)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.handleTextMessage(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.access$000(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter$3.onMessage(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter$3.onMessage(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:78)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.sendMessageText(WsFrameBase.java:399)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processDataText(WsFrameBase.java:500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processData(WsFrameBase.java:295)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processInputBuffer(WsFrameBase.java:131)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient.processSocketRead(WsFrameClient.java:73)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient.access$300(WsFrameClient.java:31)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient$WsFrameClientCompletionHandler.completed(WsFrameClient.java:131)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient$WsFrameClientCompletionHandler.completed(WsFrameClient.java:114)
    at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126)
    at sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Invoker.java:218)
    at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: I use session.subscribe("/user/queue/position-updates", ...) and session.subscribe("/queue/position-updates", ...)   both of them cannot work

Comment: It is the Exception:

Comment: It seems like you don't have configured any org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConverter in web socket configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add a StringMessageConverter to Client, it works.

```
WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(webSocketClient);
stompClient.setMessageConverter(new StringMessageConverter());
```

But how to customize our own MessageConverter? Is there any article?

Comment: No this does not work. It says no suitable converter.

Comment: This works. Actually depends on what you send from the server. In my case, I was sending a string value.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, the server was sending both `json` and `raw string` messages on different channels.
To be able to handle both cases, I went through the `MessageConverter` implementations and found `CompositeMessageConverter`, which allows multiple converters to be setup on the client.

Code:

```java
List<MessageConverter> converters = new ArrayList<MessageConverter>();
converters.add(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter()); // used to handle json messages
converters.add(new StringMessageConverter()); // used to handle raw strings

client.setMessageConverter(new CompositeMessageConverter(converters));
```

The `StompFrameHandler` will then decide, based on what `getPayloadType()` returns, which converter to use.

Comment: This was helpful, I struggled a lot till I reached your answer.

Answer (score 1):

add a SimpleMessageConverter to Client, it works.

```
stompClient.setMessageConverter(new SimpleMessageConverter());
```

Comment: `SimpleMessageConverter` is default, so this makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't have configured any org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConverter in web socket configuration.
 If you have jackson jar on your class path then it will be automatically picked up for json conversion. For other convertors , you need to configure it in WebSocket Config file .

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
 @ComponentScan(SpringScanPackageNames)
  public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer { 
@Override
public boolean configureMessageConverters(List<MessageConverter> arg0) {

    StringMessageConverter strConvertor = new StringMessageConverter();
    arg0.add(strConvertor);
    return true;
}
// Other config
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (though I was sending custom objects) and what worked for me was to simply set the Jackson2Message message converter as

```
webSocketStompClient.messageConverter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter()
```

I found useful info (and examples) about this on: https://github.com/Noozen/spring-boot-websocket-client#the-java-client